# Dynamic authentication with Ribbon and @LoadBalanced

Tags: java, spring-boot, load-balancing, resttemplate, netflix-ribbon

I've got a microservice that suports HttpBasic authentication for two users, *user* and *admin*, with different authorizations. Now I've got a web app asking for a login and delegating the operations to the first microservice.

I am using `@LoadBalanced` and `RestTemplateBuilder` this way

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.basicAuthorization("x", "x").build();
}
```

to get an authorized / load balanced `RestTemplate` to access my microservice, but this design implies that the credentials are always gonna be *x - x*, no matter what *user* and *password* are used to log in the web app.

I know I could use something like this

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

public String callSecureService() {
   // ... get principal and password
   RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization([user], [password]).build();
   return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/secureAPI",String.class);
}
```

to call the microservice with the credentials used to log in the web app, but that means losing the load balancing capabilities of ribbon, I think.

So, my question is, is there a way to have both catches (load balancing and dynamic authentication)? Or am I understanding something wrong and the design should not be like that?

(example code taken from javadeveloperzone.com[1](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-resttemplate-basic-authentication/))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution thanks to [here](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring_ribbon). Bassically we don't use `@LoadBalanced` anymore and instead we use a `LoadBalancerClient` combined with the `RestTemplateBuilder` to provide authorization per request. I'll leave the relevant code below. Thanks everybody.

```
@Autowired
protected RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

@Autowired
private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;

protected String serviceAlias;

public EmpleadosWebService(String serviceAlias) {
    this.serviceAlias = serviceAlias;
}

private RestTemplate getRestTemplateWithCurrentAuth() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization(auth.getName(), (String) auth.getCredentials()).build();
}

private String getBaseUrl() {
    ServiceInstance serviceInstance = loadBalancer.choose(this.serviceAlias);
    // We could log this string to check the load balancing
    return serviceInstance.getUri().toString();
}

public Empleado getEmpleado(String cif) {
    return getRestTemplateWithCurrentAuth().getForObject(this.getBaseUrl() + "/empleados/{cif}",
            Empleado.class, cif);
}

...
```

One more thing: to gain access to credentials (password) from Spring 3.1 onwards we need to configure `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` like this

```
auth.eraseCredentials(false)
```

or credentials will be erased from memory just after login.